# New line after return causes compile error

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS code looks like this:

```
module.directive('myDir', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
  return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
            }
        }
    }]);
```

This compiles without problem. However, if I place a new line after the return statement, an exception occurs. Why?:

```
module.directive('myDir', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)
{
  return
  {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, el, attrs, controller) {
            }
        }
    }]);
```

EDIT: This appears to be a bug in AngularJS.

Comment: What does `compiles` mean in your context? Is it just a jshint error.

Comment: I was wondering about that as well. I don't think I've ever compiled any javascript.

Comment: Compile means run the code in your browser - daaah!

Comment: Javascript is interpreted, not compiled

Comment: Is that what compile means to you?

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS does not run Javascript files - your browser does that. It does not even interpret them - your browser does that, too. It is extremely unlikely that a newline would produce such a behavior.

Javascript DOES however have a characteristic that trips up a lot of developers coming from other languages like Java that enforce things like semicolons more strictly... In Javascript, semicolons are considered 'optional' in many circumstances - they're implied at the end of most lines. The problem is that this means code formatting is essential, and a good IDE, too - it will help you catch issues like this.

If you paste your code into Plnkr you will immediately see the errors:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QBqe8qqZQkxy52AKPdj9

Compare the other two files there (fixed.js and better.js) to see the different formatting. You have two implied semicolons, one of which is the source of your problem. In Javascript you cannot do this:

```
return
{
```

to start an object that will be returned by the return statement. Return is a statement all on its own and it's perfectly valid to return nothing. The Javascript interpreter will put an implied semicolon here and blow up on the rest of your function because it will no longer be valid.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to follow up that I too have reproduced this behavior where newline after return does indeed generate this runtime error!

I can supply html file and small angular.js file with the following lines at the beginning of the file:

/**

- @license AngularJS v1.2.26
- (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
- License: MIT
  */

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).